# Is it possible to have duplicates of the same POST data over HTTPS?

Tags: security, post, ssl, https

For example.. the POST request contains command to the server to give User X $10. It's sent via HTTPS so all is good from man-in-middle attack.

However, is it possible for attacker to sniff the packet (ignoring the contents), and then create duplicates of the same packet, and then send multiple copies of it to the server as if they're coming from a legit source.

If one POST request increments user X account balance by $10, wouldn't this kind of exploit enable user X account to have $100 if the same packet is retransmitted 10 times?

Does HTTPS has some token check mechanism to prevent this kind of attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does HTTPS has some token check mechanism to prevent this kind of attack?

SSL connections are save against replay attacks.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Any resources that I can refer to on this?

Comment: @l33t:  I know that it can be hard to use [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=ssl+replay+attack) but you'll find all the information you need there within the first results.

Comment: appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not token check mechanism exactly but a concept of Page indexing and Crawling. I am not much sure of the details, but it is well explained in the following links :

[Cross Site Forgeries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

[Five steps to secure duplicate contents in https](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/5-easy-steps-to-fix-secure-page-https-duplicate-content/)

Comment: The first link provided me some insights on my problem, it seems that I have to implement a CSRF Token system whereby each token can only be used once per transaction, and if the same token is sent twice for the same transaction, it'll be detected as fraud. Am I right?